# Simplest way to compute the derivative of a function of the kind $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

Sorry if this question was asked before... I was searching and I dont found something about that.

Suppose that I have a function on the complexes, that is $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$, and I want to evaluate it (total) derivative. I know that I can write the function as a function in $\Bbb R^2$ of the kind $f\mapsto g:=(\Re(f),\Im(f))$, and after see if the function $g$ is totally differentiable and, when it happen, if the Cauchy-Riemann equations holds to see if the original function $f$ is complex differentiable in this region.

But probably there is some shortcut to this workaround, and this is what Im searching for.

EDIT: because some trolls voted to close this question by the supposed reason that "this is not related to the Wolfram mathematical software" I must declare that I want a way to evaluate the derivative of a complex function **in Wolfram Mathematica**, of course! :)

By example the following code

```
f[z_]:= D[z^2,z]
```

when called after, by example for `f[3+I]` says that `3+I`is not a correct variable. So I must found other method.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't intend to ask this on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @b3m2a1 of course NOT. Read my edit please.

Comment: See `Assuming`. e.g., `Assuming[z ~Element~ Complexes, D[z^2, z]]`. Also maybe give the intro tutorials a look. `f[3+I]` insert `3+I` anywhere it sees `z`. So that expanded to `D[(3+I)^2, 3+I]` which is, of course, an improper usage of `D`. Note that `D[(3 + I)^2, z]` works.

Comment: If the answers in the linked question do not solve your problem, please edit your question to explain why.

Comment: One method is `Clear[f, x, z];  f[z_] = D[x^2, x] /. x -> z` and then `f /@ {x, z, 3 + I}` will evaluate the way we want.  But if `x` and `z` already have values that cannot be cleared, another method is `Clear[f];  f[z_] := Module[{x}, D[x^2, x] /. x -> z]`, and then `f/@{x, z, 3+I}` will evaluate the way we want.  Note the use of `Set` in the first method and `SetDelayed` in the second method.